unable to set SPARK_HOME in tox.ini
Pyspark is installed using pip install in a virtual environment.
On the basis of the tox documentation, setenv is placed under the `[testenv]' section.
Here is the code that I got in the tox.ini file
tox.ini

[tox]
envlist = linters, py, report
isolated_build = True

[testenv]
passenv = *
skip_install = True
allowlist_externals = poetry
setenv =
    JAVA_HOME=$env:JAVA_HOME_17_X64
    SPARK_HOME=%VIRTUAL_ENV%\Scripts\python  %VIRTUAL_ENV%\Scripts\find_spark_home.py

How when i run tox, all the tests fail since neither JAVA_HOME nor SPARK_HOME is set. I have executed the commands outside of tox and they give the correct output. What am I missing here ?

setenv =
    JAVA_HOME=$env:JAVA_HOME_17_X64
    SPARK_HOME=%VIRTUAL_ENV%\Scripts\python  %VIRTUAL_ENV%\Scripts\find_spark_home.py

$env: is perhaps the syntax from PowerShell. %VIRTUAL_ENV% is from Cmd. Neither is used in tox.ini. The syntax in tox.ini is {env:KEY}:
setenv =
    JAVA_HOME={env:JAVA_HOME_17_X64}

It seems you're trying to run a script to get SPARK_HOME. I don't think it's possible in setenv
